# Adding a smaller bitmap to a larger bitmap multiple times

Tags: android

Hi and thanks in advance,

I am writing a Sudoku Solver which uses OCR (essentially) for Android. The OCR part works but i am having issues with the blank spaces. To get around this i figured the best way would be to insert a '0' character in these spaces, as that also rings true with the Sudoku solution algorithm i have already written.

I have already turned the camera image black and white and removed the lines but i am unsure how to add the '0' bitmap to the larger one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

James

Comment: can you elaborate? How are the bitmaps arranged currently?

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. The images currently are as follows, the smaller image is saved as a drawable and the larger image, i.e. camera image is saved on the sd card after having had some work already done to it. Does that help at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to draw on top of a currently existing bitmap, you can use [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas(android.graphics.Bitmap)):

```
Bitmap original = ... read in bitmap ...
Bitmap copy = original.copy(original.getConfig(), true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(copy);
  ... use canvas drawBitmap routines to draw the smaller bitmap ...
  ... write bitmap back to the sdcard ...
```

Is this what you intended?

Comment: I think we are on the same line yes, but does this method allow me action this from within a loop as the '0' image will need to be located at varying points over the main image due to different puzzles. I was hoping to run a 'loop' to scan the image for a block of 40*40 white pixels (which works) the add the '0' bitmap at this location, I should have put that in the initial question looking back.

Comment: yes, just run drawBitmap in a loop after you create the Canvas.